# jQuery wait for onChange handler to finish for bulk change (with AJAX calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button my form that selects multiple checkboxes within a table

I would like the lines of code directly below to only fire once all the change handlers have completed. The change handlers contain `AJAX` calls

```
    $('td input:checkbox.checkbox-excluded:not(:checked):not(.sibling-downloaded-checked)', table).prop('checked', true).change();
//ONLY FIRE AFTER ALL HANDLERS COMPLETED
            console.log('Post change event');
            setExcludeButton(table);
            refreshSummaryDetails(interfaceId, fileId);
            resetResubmissionButtonState();
```

My event handler is as follows...

```
 $('input.checkbox-excluded').on('change', function () {
           ...

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'PATCH',
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?